# Regarding Inventory Mgt System site

Tags: asp.net

We are developing a website to maintain inventory management. our website will be opend on multiple counters that are placed remotely. The main problem is to indetify each counter like if website is opened on first counter then automatically it identify its counter and store that counter sale in database. Before we use ip address but using data card each time a new ip-address is allocated. So it can not be done. pls help us

Comment: This question is not about a specific programming problem. It's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following option.

1. Make a users table and assign a userId to each counter along with
   password.
2. Use the specific userId to identify which counter has logged in to
   the website.
3. Save records in your database with the id referencing to the logged in user.

**Update**

You can also use windows authentication instead of forms authentication. You will get the PC name if you are on a local active directory network. But this will not work if you are moving your site on the internet.

Comment: No. if we login on another pc then it will logined successfully. and that pc will be considered 1st counter.

Comment: Second thing is that it must be fully auto system. Automatically indeify the pc when we open that site. because it will be handled by operators thay cant understand

Comment: actually site is totally online based and we use data-card for internet.